# Three20 -[TTStyledLinkNode findLastSibling:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, xcode, three20

I add three20 to my project with Xcode 4.1(Build 4B110) use ttmodule.py. Everyting is OK when I just import  and use some feature.

then I get a SIGABRT error and crash when I use the **TTStyledTextLabel** like this:

```
    NSString* kText = @"<a href=\"http://www.google.com\">Google</a>";
    TTStyledTextLabel* label = [[[TTStyledTextLabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 1)] autorelease];
    label.text = [TTStyledText textFromXHTML:kText lineBreaks:YES URLs:YES];
    [self.view addSubview:label];
```

and the Console error info:

```
    -[TTStyledLinkNode findLastSibling:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x5e830a0
    *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[TTStyledLinkNode findLastSibling:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x5e830a0'
    *** Call stack at first throw:
    (
     0   CoreFoundation                      0x0192a5a9 __exceptionPreprocess + 185
     1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x01a7e313 objc_exception_throw + 44
     2   CoreFoundation                      0x0192c0bb -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 187
     3   CoreFoundation                      0x0189b966 ___forwarding___ + 966
     4   CoreFoundation                      0x0189b522 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 50
     5   Xxxxxxxxx                           0x000fc922 -[TTStyledElement addChild:] + 148
     6   Xxxxxxxxx                           0x0010584d -[TTStyledTextParser addNode:] + 176
     7   Xxxxxxxxx                           0x00105ca8 -[TTStyledTextParser parseURLs:] + 479
     8   Xxxxxxxxx                           0x00106b5c -[TTStyledTextParser parseText:URLs:] + 55
     9   Xxxxxxxxx                           0x00106f30 -[TTStyledTextParser parseText:] + 595
     10  Xxxxxxxxx                           0x00105a85 -[TTStyledTextParser flushCharacters] + 104
     11  Xxxxxxxxx                           0x0010690e -[TTStyledTextParser parser:didEndElement:namespaceURI:qualifiedName:] + 36
     12  Foundation                          0x01657959 _endElementNs + 453
     13  libxml2.2.dylib                     0x01dc67c7 xmlParseXMLDecl + 1346
     14  libxml2.2.dylib                     0x01dd14d1 xmlParseChunk + 3984
     15  Foundation                          0x0165715a -[NSXMLParser parse] + 321
     16  Xxxxxxxxx                           0x00106cd6 -[TTStyledTextParser parseXHTML:] + 256
     17  Xxxxxxxxx                           0x001039bb +[TTStyledText textFromXHTML:lineBreaks:URLs:] + 195
     18  Xxxxxxxxx                           0x000038fa -[Xxxxxxxxx someMethod] + 2282
```

Is there a bug of Three20? I have no idea for this.

Comment: I think the real question is Three20's category method doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Do your other linker flags contain `-ObjC`?

As you already mentioned it looks to me as if the categories are not linked correctly. The most common reason for this would be to not specify `-ObjC` as linker flag. Or to use `-Objc` be accident, like I did before.

If you already got `-ObjC` you may try to add `-all_load` to other linker flags, but that should not be necessary anymore with a recent version of Xcode or Three20.

Comment: I have already add **-ObjC** and **-all_load** to other linker flags but the problem is still there.

Comment: Finally, I add all Three20's files to my project(not copy), and It work fine :D

Comment: What do you mean by "add all files, not copy"? You are supposed to *link* to the static libraries, that are compiled by the three20 projects. Look here: http://three20.info/article/2010-10-06-Adding-Three20-To-Your-Project

Comment: I have linked to three20, but some file doesn't compiled，such as some category's source file. So I drag all files of three20 to my project to make sure all of they are compiled.